# Selenium - Select fields won't save via Remote Webdrive

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, firefox

I have to test an web application written in React. I want to pick option from select field:

```
HTML
<select id="martial_status" class="form-control" name="martial_status">
<option value="" hidden="">---</option>
<option value="1">wolny</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to set this field on "value"=1 using two methods:

```
martial_status = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "martial_status")
martial_status.select_by_value('1')
```

or

```
el = driver.find_element_by_id("martial_status")
        for option in el.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
            if option.text == 'wolny':
                option.click()
                break
```

Both of them, works properly only with local webdriver:

```
cls.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
cls.driver.implicitly_wait(20)
```

When I'm using remote Webdriver selected values are not saved:

```
cls.driver = webdriver.Remote(
             command_executor='http://xx.xx.xx.xx:5555/wd/hub',
             desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX)
```

Test is not retrieving any errors. From Selenium_standalone_server console started at remote server which is executing the remote test, I assume that the select is found:

```
14:31:16.993 INFO - Executing: [find element: By.id: martial_status])
14:31:17.002 INFO - Done: [find element: By.id: martial_status]
14:31:17.063 INFO - Executing: [tag name: 15 [[FirefoxDriver: Firefox on LINUX (661c3804-f7e8-470a-b516-95ad449efb8b)] -> id: martial_status]])
14:31:17.070 INFO - Done: [tag name: 15 [[FirefoxDriver: Firefox on LINUX (661c3804-f7e8-470a-b516-95ad449efb8b)] -> id: martial_status]]
14:31:17.130 INFO - Executing: [get element attribute: 15 [[FirefoxDriver: Firefox on LINUX (661c3804-f7e8-470a-b516-95ad449efb8b)] -> id: martial_status], multiple])
14:31:17.143 INFO - Done: [get element attribute: 15 [[FirefoxDriver: Firefox on LINUX (661c3804-f7e8-470a-b516-95ad449efb8b)] -> id: martial_status], multiple]
14:31:17.204 INFO - Executing: [find child elements: 15 [[FirefoxDriver: Firefox on LINUX (661c3804-f7e8-470a-b516-95ad449efb8b)] -> id: martial_status], By.cssSelector: option[value ="1"]])
14:31:17.212 INFO - Done: [find child elements: 15 [[FirefoxDriver: Firefox on LINUX (661c3804-f7e8-470a-b516-95ad449efb8b)] -> id: martial_status], By.cssSelector: option[value ="1"]]
14:31:17.272 INFO - Executing: [is selected: 16 [[[[FirefoxDriver: Firefox on LINUX (661c3804-f7e8-470a-b516-95ad449efb8b)] -> id: martial_status]] -> css selector: option[value ="1"]]])
14:31:17.278 INFO - Done: [is selected: 16 [[[[FirefoxDriver: Firefox on LINUX (661c3804-f7e8-470a-b516-95ad449efb8b)] -> id: martial_status]] -> css selector: option[value ="1"]]]
14:31:17.337 INFO - Executing: [click: 16 [[[[FirefoxDriver: Firefox on LINUX (661c3804-f7e8-470a-b516-95ad449efb8b)] -> id: martial_status]] -> css selector: option[value ="1"]]])
14:31:17.376 INFO - Done: [click: 16 [[[[FirefoxDriver: Firefox on LINUX (661c3804-f7e8-470a-b516-95ad449efb8b)] -> id: martial_status]] -> css selector: option[value ="1"]]]
```

But after save and re-enter, I see that the select is not set.
Same code, local webdriver and selected fields are ok.
Any ideas who to solve this problem? :)

Comment: At least in your example your missing a closing parentheses.

Comment: The id is `education`, not `martial_status`

Comment: sorry for incomplete question, missclick and i send it to early:(

Comment: @JeremyFarrell I copied wrong select to the example

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative XPath to select the element.
i.e. `(//option[@value='1'])`

**Reference**: https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html